# How to get the last inserted _id from MongoDB using node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get the lastly inserted `_id` from a `MongoDB` document. I am not sure how to do this, here is what I tried.
I need to send the `_id` using `res.status(200).send(id)`

Here is what I tried so far...

```
router.route("/last/inserted/assignment/id").get((req, res) => {
  AssignmentDB.find({})
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .limit(1);  
});
```

Comment: I am using `expressJs` and `mongoose` and this solution is not how you do it in `express` and `mongoose`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting a document according to when it was created...

```
router.get("/last/inserted/assignment/id", (req, res) => {
  AssignmentDB.findOne().sort({createdAt: -1}).exec(function(err, post) {
  if (err) {return err}
  console.log(post)
});
```

Also **NOTE** The other mistake I've correctd in your code.  You should correct that too.